# I am trying to switch values in table cells using angularjs... can i use ngbind or ngmodel or something else?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a table cell clickable. When the cell is clicked it will switch the contents from one cell to another. I want to make a basic chess game out of this click action by eventually using angular.element to get the clicked elements and setting the second clicked square equal to the first clicked.html(). Is this possible in AngluarJs using a MEAN somehow?

My current code looks like this but the table cell isn't changing or doing anything when I click.

```js
app.controller('ChessCtrl' , ['$http', '$scope', '$document', function 
  ChessCtrl($http, $scope, $document) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test1 = angular.element(document.getElementById("A1")); 
  vm.test2 = "";
  vm.test3 = "This is a test";

  $scope.click = function() {
    var temp = vm.test3;
    vm.test2 = temp;
    vm.test3 = "";
  }

  }]);
```

```html
<div ng-Controller="ChessCtrl">
<div class="content">
<div class="left">
  <table style="width: 75%">
    <tr>
    <td id="A1" ><a ng-bind="vm.test3" ng-click="click()"></a></td>
    <td class="grey" ng-bind="vm.test2"><a ng-bind="vm.test2" ng-click="click()"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Obviously I am missing something but I have tried adding to a DB and pulling it back out. I have tried ng-model and ng-bind for holding the variables. I am just lost on if or how I can get the td to be clickable and also switch where what is clicked displays. Thanks!

NOTE: disregard test1 in this example... I was using that earlier for testing getting the HTML out of the element.

Comment: your code having error, in code snippet, please provide full code

Comment: I am new to this and have only asked a couple questions before this, so I am sorry for my ignorance. Should I be adding my whole file? That is quite big. Plus there are many other files / dependancies that run this in my AWS Lightsail. The code provided is simply what I have been working on and trying to get table elements to switch their texts from one to the other.

Comment: in the above example or code snippet, what you want to show us!!?

Comment: Again, I apologize for my ignorance with how the snippets work, but I would guess the snippet is having an error because AngularJS requires other dependancies to compile. I simply just want to know (because what I have isn't working) if it is possible to somehow have a table element clickable and then make the 2nd td display what was in the first td after being clicked. Essentially I want to switch innerHTML's of the table elements. Which I feel I asked in the question. Sorry for the error in the snippet but I don't know what else to add without adding the whole project.

Comment: okay, wait i am writing code, will provide solution, and thanks to explain you problem again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML doesn't need the `<a>` tag. Simply set the CSS style to `cursor: pointer`.

Also the `ng-bind` directive isn't necessary, simply bind model to HTML with double brace `{{ }}` expressions.

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('ChessCtrl' , function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test2 = "♔";
  vm.test3 = "test";

  vm.switch = function() {
    var temp = vm.test2;
    vm.test2 = vm.test3;
    vm.test3 = temp;
  }
});
```

```css
.red  { background-color: red; }
.grey { background-color: grey; }
td {
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChessCtrl as vm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="red"  ng-click="vm.switch()">{{vm.test3}}</td>
      <td class="grey" ng-click="vm.switch()">{{vm.test2}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This will hopefully help a lot. Now I can probably figure out how to have it click a square and then pick a different square on the board to move to. This is neat though. I appreciate it

Comment: Read [MDN Web API Reference - HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Comment: I did vote but it says I am too low rated (because I recently just started using stack) for the vote to show. I did hit up but it said it won't change the public view. I want you to know I appreciate it a lot though.

Comment: Says I need 15 reputation for it to be publically recorded

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I try to figure out one solution that might work for you too.

I am adding code snippet have a look:

Main challange, that you are facing is, ng-bind, 
have a look to this article and find the sole purpose of ng-bind

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


  <table style="width: 75%">
    <tr>
    <td id="td1" ><a ng-bind="link1" ng-click="clickMe()"></a></td>
    <td id="td2" class="" ><a  ng-bind="link2" ng-click="clickMeAgain()"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<script>
var clickMeIsClicked = false;
var clickMeAgainIsClicked = false;

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.link1 = 'Click me to show td2';
    $scope.link2 = ' I always want to be visible, thanks td1';
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.count++;
    }
    
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
     if(!clickMeIsClicked){
          $scope.link2 = 'Click me to show td2';
          $scope.link1 = ' I always want to be visible, thanks td1';
          clickMeIsClicked = true;
  }
        else{
         $scope.link1 = 'Click me to show td2';
      $scope.link2 = ' I always want to be visible, thanks td1';
           clickMeIsClicked = false;
        }
    }
    
    $scope.clickMeAgain = function(){
     
    }
    
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```